# Problem with PoE implementation and newer switches

Tags: power, analog, poe

I am using Power over Ethernet (MP8007 as **P**owered **D**evice) and it works perfectly with old PoE switches and PoE injectors.

In this application PoE is used as a secondary power source so when the main power source is removed the secondary takes over without interruption.

New switches however I found that they are 'smart' and if the PD doesn’t draw any current, the PoE switch cuts the power to PoE circuit (another PoE PD off the shelf module works the same) and when device starts to draw current, MP8007 has a 100ms delay / timer and this causes our device to restart during take over.

I wonder if somebody could help or comment on this?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the model numbers of the old/new PoE switches, and which IEEE 802 standard(s) they support?

Comment: I used several newly bought PoE switches tp-link and netgear brand, and other higher end brand all behave the same, so I do not think it is PoE switches issue. 
Older PoE switches works like an injector or just inject 48V directly to MP8007. The standard is  IEEE 802.3af/at.

Comment: A guess: These new switches are 802.3af/at compliant, but they also have the new Green functions, and so if there's no current draw / traffic, they switch off PoE for that port until there's a new negotiation. See if you can disable 802.3az.

Comment: Thanks @MiNiMe, Now I know what to look for. This used in a consumer product and ask the user to go and change setting is not very practical. I would like to redesign the board in a way that overcome this issue.

Comment: Is the PoE just there for the power?

Comment: No, it is also used for communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class class 1-3 PD need to draw a minimum of 10mA in order to ensure that the PSE doesn't disconnect, according to the standard. In my experience Netgear PoE switches behave quite "loosely" in relation to the standard in general.

The or-ing function in the MP8007 doesn't seem to be designed for power redundancy with seamless transition from PoE to DC or vice versa in a robust way since the PD doesn't have a "maintain power signature" function that makes sure that the PSE doesn't disconnect by always drawning the minimum required power from PoE. Maybe connecting a minimum 10mA load between VDD and VSS would keep PoE from disconnecting. The load can't be activated until after the PoE input voltage has reached more than around 23V though, otherwise it will interfere with detection and classification.

Comment: I wasn't aware that ``Seagate`` made PoE switches, and from searching can't seem to find any. Did you mean a different manufacturer?

Comment: Meant Netgear. Changed